# How can I tell the user is logged into Facebook on iOS?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, authentication, ios6

I'm using the [Accounts Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Accounts/Reference/AccountsFrameworkRef/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011024) on iOS 6 to get access to Facebook. As long as the user has logged into Facebook in Settings, it works great. However, when they are *not* logged in to Facebook, my call to `-requestAccessToAccountsWithType:options:completion:` sends a generic system error to the completion block:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=6 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.accounts error 6.)"
```

Seems pretty useless. Is there some other way I'm supposed to know that the user is not logged in?

(Incidentally, this is not an issue when the user is logged in toFacebook but has disabled access to my app in Settings: that returns an unambiguous error code.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [`+isAvailableForServiceType:` in SLComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is what I need. I hadn't thought to look there, because I'm not using SLComposeViewController. But I don't see why I can't call this class method and not try to request access if it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve the same issue. I've just notice that the error code is 6 when the use has not connect the phone with facebook. It's 7 when the user is connected and press the "don't allow" button.
The documentation is available in the ACError.h file.

Comment: Oh, that looks useful. But I want to detect when the user isn't logged in before I request access.

Comment: ACAccountStore has a property "accounts" that returns an array of accounts.